# How to loop through directory and export content of excel files, workbook by workbook, sheet by sheet (VBA Macros)?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to export some tables from excel workbooks to txt files. I have managed to do this for a workbook whilst I have it open. My code will loop through the sheets of a workbook I have open, and export the content to txt files (different file for each sheet). I need it to loop through a directory of .xlsx files and do the same without any manual labor. Can anyone help?

Below is my code:

```
Sub Exportation()

    Dim directory As String
    Dim WS_Count As Integer, myFile As String, x As Integer
    Dim rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer

    directory = "C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\Testing\" ' The starting directory

    Dim fso, newFile, folder, files
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(directory)
    Set files = folder.files

    For Each file In files
        WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        For x = 1 To WS_Count

            myFile = "C:\Users\mohamednuri.beitelma\Desktop\" & Sheets(x).Name & ".txt"

            'Set rng = Selection
            Set rng = Sheets(x).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            Open myFile For Output As #1
            cnt = Sheets(x).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

            For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
                For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count

                    cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value

                    If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
                        Print #1, cellValue
                    Else
                        Print #1, cellValue & "|",
                    End If

                Next j
            Next i
        Print #1, cnt & " -- " & DateTime.Now
    Close #1
Next x

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem you have?

Comment: I need to loop through a directory of excel files and execute the code within the file loop (starting from WS_Count). Ideally, the above would loop through each file, loop through each sheet within each file, and export the content of each sheet to a txt file. However, what I have currently only execute the export command on the workbook where the above macros resides (i.e. it doesn't loop through the directory). I imagine something's wrong with the logic of the loop or perhaps my syntax. As for the loop that begins by iterating through each worksheet, it works exactly as it should. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried going step by step with a debugger?

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid I was not able to spot where it goes wrong. It doesn't generate an error. It just doesn't do what it's meant to. As opposed through going through all the files in the specified directory, it just execute the code on the active workbook where the macro resides.

Comment: is `WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count` greater than one?

Comment: Yeah, it also depends on the workbook

Comment: It is only working on the workbook with the macro because that's the only workbook you are working with: `WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count` You loop through the files just fine, but then you never open them. You still just work with the `ActiveWorkbook`. At some point towards the beginning of your loop you need to `.open(`file.name)` to get the worbook object like this: `Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=file.name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (untested):

```
Sub Exportation()

Dim directory As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws as worksheet
Dim WS_Count As Integer, myFile As String, x As Integer
Dim rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer

directory = "C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\Testing\" ' The starting directory

Dim fso, newFile, folder, files
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set folder = fso.GetFolder(directory)
Set files = folder.files

For Each file In files
    set wb = workbooks.open(filename:=file.path)
    WS_Count = wb.Worksheets.Count
    For x = 1 To WS_Count

        myFile = "C:\Users\mohamednuri.beitelma\Desktop\" & Sheets(x).Name & ".txt"

        'Set rng = Selection
        Set rng = wb.Sheets(x).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Open myFile For Output As #1
        cnt = wb.Sheets(x).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

        For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
            For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count

                cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value

                If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
                    Print #1, cellValue
                Else
                    Print #1, cellValue & "|",
                End If

            Next j
        Next i
        Print #1, cnt & " -- " & DateTime.Now
    Close #1
    Next x

Next

End Sub
```